# inputText validator doesn't display error message

Tags: jsf-2

I have a simple form that get code then display his libelle, I added a validator bean that check if the code exist.
My problem is I can't display the error message whith  when the code doesn't exist.

Here is the code:

test.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head><title>Test</title>
</h:head>
<body class="bodyMain">

<h:form>        
    <h:panelGrid columns="3">
        <h:outputText value="Code: " />
        <h:inputText id="code" value="#{myBean.code}"
            validator="#{myBean.validateCode}">
            <f:ajax execute="@this" render="libelle" listener="#{myBean.setLibelle()}"/>
        </h:inputText>
        <h:message for="code" style="color:red"/>
    </h:panelGrid>
    <h:panelGrid id="libelle" columns="2">
        <h:outputText value="Libelle: " />
        <h:outputText value="#{myBean.libelle}" />
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>       

</body>
</html>
```

MyBean.java

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MyBean implements java.io.Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String code="";
    private String libelle="";

    public String getCode() {
        return this.code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code=code;
    }       

    public String getLibelle() {
        return this.libelle;
    }

    public void setLibelle(String libelle) {
        this.libelle=libelle;
    }

    public void setLibelle() {
        if (code.compareTo("1")==0)
            libelle="One";
        else
            libelle="";
    }

    public void validateCode(FacesContext context, UIComponent toValidate, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        String code = (String)value;
        if (code.compareTo("1") != 0) {
            FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Code doesn't exist");
            throw new ValidatorException(message);
        }
    }

}
```

Thank you for your help to resolve this problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not updating the `<h:message>` component by the `<f:ajax>`. You need to give the `<h:message>` an `id` and include it in the `<f:ajax render>`.

```
<h:inputText id="code" value="#{myBean.code}" validator="#{myBean.validateCode}">
    <f:ajax execute="@this" render="libelle codeMessage" listener="#{myBean.setLibelle()}"/>
</h:inputText>
<h:message id="codeMessage" for="code" style="color:red"/>
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, don't initialize properties to empty strings. Let them by default `null`. Also, comparing objects should be done with `equals()` method, not with `compareTo()`. Finally, using a dropdown list with all available values instead of an input field would be more user friendly.